# How can I prove these summations for the legendre symbol

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, legendre-symbol

How can I prove for the Legendre symbol that:

$$\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}{\left(\frac{a(a+1)}{p}\right)}= -1 = \sum_{b=1}^{p-1}{\left(\frac{(1+b)}{p}\right)}$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Try adding and one to each sum, and reindexing the sum so that it looks like an orthogonality relation for characters.

Comment: how will changing the bounds help?

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially what I prove [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333704/sum-of-the-product-of-consecutive-legendre-symbols-is-1), after you note that $\left(\dfrac{(p-1)p}{p}\right)=\left(\dfrac{p}{p}\right)=0$. The main idea is to note that $\left(\dfrac{a(a+1)}{p}\right)=\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{a+1}{a}}{p}\right)$. Of course, you need to be familar with the fact that $\sum\limits_{a=1}^{p-1}{\left(\dfrac{a}{p}\right)}=0$ (which follows from the fact that there are exactly $\dfrac{p-1}{2}$ non-zero quadratic residues $\pmod{p}$ (for $p>2$))