# $\sum_{y=0}^{p-1 } (\frac{y^2 - b^{-1}}{p}) =-1$

Tags: number-theory, legendre-symbol

Given Legendre symbol: $(\frac{y^2 - b^{-1}}{p})$.
Please show a detailed proof of $\sum_{y=0}^{p-1 } (\frac{y^2 - b^{-1}}{p}) =-1$

Comment: There should be a typo in some LaTeX command, I don't see your formulas correctly.

Comment: @i707107 sir, can you please help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341126) shows that for<sup>(1)</sup><sup>(2)</sup> $c\neq0$ we have $$\sum_{y}\left(\frac{y(y+c)}{p}\right)=-1$$
This is done by replacing<sup>(3)</sup> $y(y+c)$ by $(y+c)/y$ which parametrizes<sup>(4)</sup> $\mathbb F_p\setminus\{1\}$, which reduces the problem to the well known<sup>(5)</sup>
$$\sum_{y}\left(\frac{y}{p}\right)=0$$

---

**In this case** the question is different in that $y^2-b$ only factors as above if $b$ is a square mod $p$.<sup>(6)</sup> What we can do is invert the order of summation:
$$\sum_{y}\left(\frac{y^2-b}{p}\right)=\sum_{x}\left(\frac{x}{p}\right) \left(1+\left(\frac{x+b}{p}\right)\right)$$
because $1+\left(\frac{x+b}{p}\right)$ is the number of solutions to $y^2-b\equiv x$.

This reduces to problem to the identity above.<sup>(7)</sup>

---

**More details**

1. Strictly speaking only for $c=1$; the general case is proved analoguously.
2. For $c=0$ all terms (except for $y=0$) are $1$, and the sum equals $p-1$
3. Note that $\left(\frac{ab}p\right) = \left(\frac{ab/a^2}p\right) = \left(\frac{b/a}p\right)$ for $a\neq 0$.
4. When $y$ runs through $1, \ldots, p-1$, $1+c/y$ runs through $2, 3, \ldots, p$: it cannot equal $1$ mod $p$, and $a = 1+c/y$ iff $y=(a-1)/c$ shows that $a$ can take all values from $2$ to $p$ (mod $p$), the only restriction being that $y \neq0$.
5. Because there are as many QR's as non QR's mod $p$ (not counting $0$)
6. It factors as $(y-b)(y+b)$, but making the change of variables $z=y-b$ gives the problem from the beginning, with $c=2b$.
7. We are left with $\sum_{x}\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)=0$ and $\sum_{x}\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)\left(\frac{x+b}{p}\right)=0$, note that $\left(\frac{ab}p\right) = \left(\frac{a}p\right)\left(\frac{b}p\right)$.

Comment: What is that identity? Or suggest any link that I can find that identity.

Comment: Which one?${}{}$

Comment: $\sum_{y=0}^{p-1} (\frac {y(y+c)}{p})=-1 $

Comment: The question I link to in the beginning is the case $c=1$, the proof for the general case is the same. The key ideas are in my answer.

Comment: How it come up that it is equal to -1? Sorry im not that familiar with legendre symbol

Comment: Because a change of variables reduces it to proving $\sum_{y \neq 1}\left(\frac{y}{p}\right)=-1$, which follows from $\sum_{y}\left(\frac{y}{p}\right)=0$

Comment: Can it be $\sum_{x=0}^{p-1} (1 + (\frac {x}{p})) (\frac {x+b}{p})= \sum_{x=0}^{p-1} (\frac {x}{p}) (1+ (\frac {x+b}{p})) $ ??

Comment: Yes, both are $0$ using $\sum_{y}\left(\frac{y}{p}\right)=0$ and $\sum_{x=0}^{p-1} (\frac {x}{p}) (\frac {x+b}{p})=0$ for $b\not\equiv 0$

Comment: Sir, can you please show a step by step proof of your answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: See edit.${}{}$