# How to prove this sum of those legendre symbols is -1?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, legendre-symbol

I want to prove $\newcommand{\jaco}[2]{\left(\frac{#1}{#2}\right)}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{p} \jaco{n^2+a}p = -1$, where $(a,p)=1$ and $p$ is an odd prime. I have seen similar problems like [sum of the product of consecutive legendre symbols is -1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333704/sum-of-the-product-of-consecutive-legendre-symbols-is-1), but I am not able to apply similar method to solve this one. Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the proof for the generalized result for $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{p}\left( \frac{ak^2+bk+c}{p} \right)$ in [here](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c146h150500p849406) or [here](http://imomath.com/index.php?options=328&lmm=0).